# C File program doesnt execute fopen

Tags: c, file, fopen

after saving the program in turbo c++,the place where its saved doesnt show the file's individual components,and its executing twice.Its for a college project.The problem seems to be for the portion of code written for opening and in the for loop

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
      int select;
      char lastname[25];
      char firstname[25];
      char address[25];
      char phonenumber[25];
} addressbook;

#define ARRAYLEN 2

addressbook a[ARRAYLEN];
FILE *fp;

int main()
{
     int i;

     fp = fopen("addressbook.dat","a+");

     for( i=0; i<ARRAYLEN ; i++)
     {
       printf("enter details\n");
       printf("enter lastname:\n");
       scanf("%s", a[i].lastname);
       printf("enter firstname:\n");
       scanf("%s", a[i].firstname);
       printf("enter address:\n");
       scanf("%s", a[i].address);
       printf("enter phone number:\n");
       scanf("%s", a[i].phonenumber);
       fwrite(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, fp); /* notice, array indexed */
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fopen("addressbook.dat", "r");
    for(i=0; i<ARRAYLEN; i++)
    {
      fread(&a[i], sizeof(a), 1, fp );
      printf("lastname:%s\n", a[i].lastname);
      printf("firstname:%s\n", a[i].firstname);
      printf("address:%s\n", a[i].address);
      printf("phonenumber:%s\n", a[i].phonenumber);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second `fopen` does not use it's return value. It should be `fp = fopen("addressbook.dat", "r");` Also, you should check `fp` to see if it is NULL and take appropriate action if so.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Post it as an answer. It is the right solution. Adding that is [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to `fread` with a closed` fp`.

Comment: Off-topic comment... your use of `scanf()` to read user input is a very, very bad practice. Consider: 1) What happens if the user enters a name / address that exceeds your field sizes? 2) What happens if the user enters multiple tokens (multiple firstnames are known to exist, and either address or phone number are *customarily* formatted containing spaces)? -- A good alternative is to read whole lines of input (using `fgets()` and resizing your buffer if you did not get the whole line), then checking how much input you've got, allocating memory dynamically, and copying from the input buffer.

Comment: @DevSolar thanks dude.that might actually help a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the use of 'fp' - File Pointer.

After the first use of fopen, you are closing it, and then use fopen again.

But this time, you are not place it return value into fp. So your following actiond (like fread) creates undetermenated results.

Please replace -

```
fopen("addressbook.dat", "r");
```

with

```
fp = fopen("addressbook.dat", "r");
```

Other problems in your code -

1. Always check for return value
2. You need to verify that values received from user, do not exceed allowed space given to variables
3. It goes without saying, but you are using fclose(fp) twice on your corrent solution

Comment: Do  you now how to format the code in answers?  (just indent the code by `4-spaces` `:)`

Comment: Thanks @David C. Rankin

Comment: That's much better, Welcome to SO.